# Create key combination to run script action

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse

I am having shoulder problems and the mouse movement is hurting my arm, so I am trying to create a simple way of navigating the mouse with `vim`-like movements. I found `xdotool` and can, for example, move my mouse up by running `xdotool mousemove_relative -- 0 -15`. Now, I would like to create a key combination to allow for moving my mouse via the `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`, keys like in `vim`. For example, I would like `F1+k` to execute `xdotool mousemove_relative -- 0 -15` or something like that.

In Kubuntu, how can I orchestrate something so that pressing `key1+key2+...+keyN` will do the same things as running `myscript.sh` in the terminal?

Comment: Well, if you're serious about dropping the mouse, I would suggest looking into tiling window managers instead. Particularly xmonad, awesome or i3